# Dynamic memory reallocation

Tags: c++, pointers

If you allocate some space dynamically for example

```
    struct node*py=new struct node;
    struct node*tr=py;
    delete py;
```

shouldn't the allocated memory still remain and not be freed since I do have another pointer pointing to the same address before the original pointer to the same is deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That's simply not how memory allocation works in C++.

If you allocate memory with `new`, and then you call `delete` on it, it *will* get deleted. The memory manager has no facility for canceling or aborting a deletion once it's begun. C++ has a tendency of doing exactly what you ask it to do, so if you don't really want to free some memory, then don't call `delete` on it yet.

If you want reference counting, try using `std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr`, if you don't have the one in `std` yet).

Comment: I think it should be `std::tr1::shared_ptr`

Comment: If your `shared_ptr` resides in `std::tr1`, then go ahead and use that one instead, @Jun. C++11 moved it to `std`, though.

Answer (score 4):

no, the heap manager just does what it's told and frees the memory.

If you want to retain the memory based on how many references you have to the memory, then consider using reference-counted pointers such as C++11 shared_ptr (see, e.g., [Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/3-most-useful-library-features-of-c0x/231300394?pgno=1)) or boost's [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Answer (score 2):

But you said it yourself - its only a pointer, therefore it doesnt know to what it points. it simply points to somewhere blindfolded.

Comment: Em..doesn't the new pointer know the location of the allocated memory from the `struct node*tr=py` line?

Comment: think of it like this: if i add another line and change to where it points, does it care to where it was pointing before? it only knows to where it points now, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

No, in c/c++ the compiler/execution environment does not track refrences to memory, new and free mark memory as in use or not in use, and any refrence counting or other higher order garbage collection is left up to your program.